# How do I get the names of the columns returned by a WbemScripting query?

Tags: delphi, wmi, wmi-query, enumerate

I have the following procedure to run a WMI query, and it works perfectly well.

```
procedure TFormMain.GetWMIOSInfo(const RemoteMachine, Username, Password: string);
var
  FSWbemLocator: OLEVariant;
  FWMIService: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject: OLEVariant;
  oEnum: IEnumvariant;
  iValue: LongWord;
begin;
  try
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
    FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(RemoteMachine, 'root\CIMV2', Username, Password);
    FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.ExecQuery(
        'select screenwidth, screenheight, status from Win32_DesktopMonitor','WQL', 0);
    try
      oEnum := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
      while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
        begin
          Listbox1.Items.Add(
            VarToStr(FWbemObject.availability) + ', ' + 
            VarToStr(FWbemObject.screenwidth)  + ', ' +
            VarToStr(FWbemObject.screenheight));

          FWbemObject := Unassigned;
        end;

    finally
      FWbemObjectSet := Unassigned;
    end;

  Except on E: Exception do
    Raise;
  end;
end;
```

I would like to alter the query to return all the fields like `select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor`. My problem is that I do not know how to determine the names of the columns that are returned by the query in `FWbemObject`. ie. I'd like to enumerate the columns in the `FWbemObject`.

```
Listbox1.Items.Add(
  VarToStr(FWbemObject.<?>) + ', ' + 
  VarToStr(FWbemObject.<?>)  + ', ' +
  ....
  VarToStr(FWbemObject.<?>));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pieter you must use the [`SWbemObject.Properties_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Property of the [`SWbemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  Object.

check this sample.

```
program GetWMI_Info;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;


procedure  GetWin32_DesktopMonitorInfo;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

  FProperties   : OLEVariant;
  oEnumProp     : IEnumvariant;
  iValueProp    : LongWord;
  FPropObj      : OLEVariant;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor','WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
  begin

    FProperties   := FWbemObject.Properties_;
    oEnumProp     := IUnknown(FProperties._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    while oEnumProp.Next(1, FPropObj, iValueProp) = 0 do
    begin
       Writeln(FPropObj.Name);
       FPropObj:=Unassigned; //prevent memory leak
    end;

    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;//prevent memory leak
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_DesktopMonitorInfo;
      Readln;
    finally
    CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
        Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: For the meaning of the listed properties take a look at the [Win32_DesktopMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122.aspx) official documentation.

Comment: Is that `Unassigned` statement really necessary? I thought the OleVariant would get finalized automatically at the end of the function.

Comment: Rob, not in this case because the code is `if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then` but if you uses something like `while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do` you need to set to `Unassigned` to avoid memory leaks inside of the loop.

Comment: @Rob, it is when dealing with COM. Failing to do so is one of the biggest issues with automating Office applications; you end up with an invisible copy of Word or Excel running that you have to stop using Task Manager.

Comment: So, if you need to set `Unassigned` when you use it in a loop, then does that mean your `oEnumProp` loop leaks memory since it doesn't unassign `FPropObj`? @Ken, what you're saying sounds like a bug. Is that right? Is it a bug in the `Next` implementor that doesn't properly clear the given variable before populating it with the next item in the sequence, or is it a bug in Delphi that doesn't clear it at the end of the function?

Comment: @Rob , yes the when i wrote the sample app i forgot put the `FPropObj:=Unassigned;` in the `oEnumProp` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The [`SWbemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393741%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface exposes the [`Properties_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393781%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property which is a collection (so you can enumerate it probably in the same way as you enumerate the `SWebmObjectSet` interface returned by `ExecQuery`). The items of this collection are [SWbemProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393804%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interfaces which expose `Name` and `Value` properties.

Comment: Thank you for additionally indicating the exposed (Name, Value) properties.